# javascript - regex - match list and range of repetitive tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an html string:

```
"this is <b>bold</b>, and then again - <b>another bolded</b> one"
```

My desired result is to get a list of all  tags + the index of each tag

```
results = [ 
   { 
     tag: '<b>bold</b>',
     text: 'bold',
     index: 8
   },

   { 
     tag: '<b>another bolded</b>',
     text: 'another bolded',
     index: 38
   }

]
```

I tries using this regex

```
/\<b\>(.*)\<\/b\>/
```

but it gives me this result instead

```
results = [ 
   { 
     tag: '<b>bold</b>, and then again - <b>another bolded</b>',
     text: 'bold</b>, and then again - <b>another bolded',
     index: 8
   }
]
```

this javascript I use now is:

```
var func = function() {
    var text = "this is <b>bold</b>, and then again - <b>another bolded</b> one";
    var match = text.match(/\<b\>(.*)\<\/b\>/);

    var result = [
        {
            tag: match[0],
            text: match[1],
            index: match.index
        }
    ]

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the js where you test the regex.

Comment: thank you @l-portet, ive updated the function I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace` to loop over the string finding the tags, text, and index:

```js
const string = "this is <b>bold</b>, and then again - <b>another bolded</b> one";
const matches = [];

string.replace(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g, (tag, text, index) => {
  matches.push({tag, text, index});
});

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try inserting a `?` to make `(.*)` less greedy

`/\<b\>(.*?)\<\/b\>/`

https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

For the index of the opening and closing tags - the index of the opening tag is known, as it is `match.index` of `/\<b\>(.*)\<\/b\>/`.

For the closing tag, add the index of the opening tag in `text` to the index of the closing tag in `match[0]`.

```
        {
            tag: match[0],
            text: match[1],
            index: match.index,
            closingTagIndex: match[0].match(/(<\/b\>)/).index + match.index
        }
```

Comment: thank you! it did the job regex wise - but how can I get the index of each tag now?

Comment: The index of < from <b>?